# How do I apply a binary mask and STFT to produce an audio file?

Tags: python, audio, linear-algebra, spectrogram, librosa

So here's the idea: you can generate a spectrogram from an audio file using shorttime Fourier transform (stft). Then some people have generated something called a "binary mask" to generate different audio (ie. with background noise removed etc.) from the inverse stft.

Here's what I understand:

stft is a simple equation that is applied to the audio file, which generates the information that can easily be displayed a spectrogram.
By taking the inverse of the stft matrix, and multiplying it by a matrix of the same size (the binary matrix) you can create a new matrix with information to generate an audio file with the masked sound.

**Once I do the matrix multiplication, how is the new audio file created?**

It's not much but here's what I've got in terms of code:

```
from librosa import load
from librosa.core import stft, istft
y, sample_rate = load('1.wav')
spectrum = stft(y)
back_y = istft(spectrum)
```

Thank you, and here are some slides that got me this far. I'd appreciate it if you could give me an example/demo in python

Answer (score 1):

Librosa's STFT is full-featured so unless you're very careful with how you manipulate the spectrum, you won't get a sensible output from its `istft`.

Here's a pair of functions, `stft` and `istft`, that I wrote from scratch that represent the forward and inverse STFT, along with a helper method that gives you the time and frequency locations of each pixel in the STFT array, plus a demo:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.fft as fft


def stft(x, Nwin, Nfft=None):
    """
    Short-time Fourier transform: convert a 1D vector to a 2D array

    The short-time Fourier transform (STFT) breaks a long vector into disjoint
    chunks (no overlap) and runs an FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) on each chunk.

    The resulting 2D array can 

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : array_like
        Input signal (expected to be real)
    Nwin : int
        Length of each window (chunk of the signal). Should be ≪ `len(x)`.
    Nfft : int, optional
        Zero-pad each chunk to this length before FFT. Should be ≥ `Nwin`,
        (usually with small prime factors, for fastest FFT). Default: `Nwin`.

    Returns
    -------
    out : complex ndarray
        `len(x) // Nwin` by `Nfft` complex array representing the STFT of `x`.

    See also
    --------
    istft : inverse function (convert a STFT array back to a data vector)
    stftbins : time and frequency bins corresponding to `out`
    """
    Nfft = Nfft or Nwin
    Nwindows = x.size // Nwin
    # reshape into array `Nwin` wide, and as tall as possible. This is
    # optimized for C-order (row-major) layouts.
    arr = np.reshape(x[:Nwindows * Nwin], (-1, Nwin))
    stft = fft.rfft(arr, Nfft)
    return stft


def stftbins(x, Nwin, Nfft=None, d=1.0):
    """
    Time and frequency bins corresponding to short-time Fourier transform.

    Call this with the same arguments as `stft`, plus one extra argument: `d`
    sample spacing, to get the time and frequency axes that the output of
    `stft` correspond to.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : array_like
        same as `stft`
    Nwin : int
        same as `stft`
    Nfft : int, optional
        same as `stft`
    d : float, optional
        Sample spacing of `x` (or 1 / sample frequency), units of seconds.
        Default: 1.0.

    Returns
    -------
    t : ndarray
        Array of length `len(x) // Nwin`, in units of seconds, corresponding to
        the first dimension (height) of the output of `stft`.
    f : ndarray
        Array of length `Nfft`, in units of Hertz, corresponding to the second
        dimension (width) of the output of `stft`.
    """
    Nfft = Nfft or Nwin
    Nwindows = x.size // Nwin
    t = np.arange(Nwindows) * (Nwin * d)
    f = fft.rfftfreq(Nfft, d)
    return t, f


def istft(stftArr, Nwin):
    """
    Inverse short-time Fourier transform (ISTFT)

    Given an array representing the output of `stft`, convert it back to the
    original samples.

    Parameters
    ----------
    stftArr : ndarray
        Output of `stft` (or something the same size)
    Nwin : int
        Same input as `stft`: length of each chunk that the STFT was calculated
        over.

    Returns
    -------
    y : ndarray
        Data samples corresponding to STFT data.

    See also:
    stft : the forward transform
    """
    arr = fft.irfft(stftArr)[:, :Nwin]
    return np.reshape(arr, -1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sampleRate = 100.0  # Hertz
    N = 1024
    Nwin = 64

    # Generate a chirp: start frequency at 5 Hz and going down at 2 Hz/s
    time = np.arange(N) / sampleRate  # seconds
    x = np.cos(2 * np.pi * time * (5 - 2 * 0.5 * time))

    # Test with Nfft bigger than Nwin
    Nfft = Nwin * 2
    s = stft(x, Nwin, Nfft=Nfft)
    y = istft(s, Nwin)

    # Make sure the stft and istft are inverses. Caveat: `x` and `y` won't be
    # the same length if `N/Nwin` isn't integral!
    maxerr = np.max(np.abs(x - y))
    assert (maxerr < np.spacing(1) * 10)

    # Test `stftbins`
    t, f = stftbins(x, Nwin, Nfft=Nfft, d=1 / sampleRate)
    assert (len(t) == s.shape[0])
    assert (len(f) == s.shape[1])

    try:
        import pylab as plt
        plt.imshow(np.abs(s), aspect="auto", extent=[f[0], f[-1], t[-1], t[0]])
        plt.xlabel('frequency (Hertz)')
        plt.ylabel('time (seconds (start of chunk))')
        plt.title('STFT with chirp example')
        plt.show()
    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        pass
```

This is in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/fasiha/5702e57a54e9280d117dec9ea1a50e78) if that's easier for you to read.

The entire module assumes real-only data and uses Numpy's `rfft` functions. You can definitely generalize this to complex data (or use librosa), but for your application (audio masking), using the real-only transforms makes it easier to ensure that everything works out and the output of the inverse STFT is real-only (it's easy to mess this up if you're doing the fully-general complex STFT, where you need to be careful in maintaining symmetries).

The demo first generates some test data and confirms that the `istft` on the `stft` of the data produces the data again. The test data is a chirp that starts at 5 Hz and goes down at 2 Hz per second, so over ~10 seconds of data, the chirp's frequency wraps around and ends up at around 15 Hz. The demo plots the STFT (by taking the absolute value of the STFT array):

[image: STFT of chirp in the demo]

So

1. put this code in a `stft.py` file,
2. import it as `import stft`,
3. compute an STFT as `spectrum = stft.stft(y, 128)`,
4. visualize your spectrum as shown in the demo (be sure to prepend `stft.` to functions defined in `stft.py`!),
5. pick what frequencies you want to attenuate/amplify and apply those effects on the `spectrum` array, before
6. finally getting the processed audio via `back_y = stft.istft(spectrum, 128)`.

Masking/amplifying/attenuating frequency content means just scaling some bins of the `spectrum` array. If you have specific questions on how to do that, let us know. But this hopefully will give you a foolproof way of applying arbitrary effects.

If you really want to use librosa's functions, let us know and we can show you how to do that too.

Comment: Could you please show how to do with librosa as well?